# How to setState the props value in ComponentDidUpdate in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
componentDidUpdate(){
 var date = this.props.navigation.state.params.selected_date

 this.setState({
   sleepinputs_date: date
 })
}
```

When I try to setState the props value it throws an error  "[image]

Comment: The function itself looks fine, you're not doing anything wrong there, however, that implies that you, or something is causing lots of repeated lifecycle refreshes

Comment: Here's a quote from the docs: "You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to react docs, you will get an argument in   `componentDidUpdate`. You can set state only if you use a conditional like the following.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
//    Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
      if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
        this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
      }
    }
```

Basically you are comparing the old props with the new ones. Only if they are different, you can keep updating or modifying the value. If previous props are the same as current props, why you botter to set state them again.

Answer (score 3):

You had created infinite state update. 
Inside **componentDidUpdate** you update the state, when it updates the state, **componentDidUpdate** invokes again in this stuff keeps going without ending.

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to pass the date from one component to another

Comment: What is the solution to avoid this infinite loop error?

Comment: the you should use props for passing data from one component to another

Comment: @aravind_reddy is right. To solve this you need to get the date and assign it to the state inside  **componentDidMount** function. Pass this state value as a **prop** in any other component.